End Test Case in playwright when the error code is 500
I have a test case where I would like the test case to fail or end when the error code is 500.
But the test.fail() does not immediately stop the test case.
page.on('console', msg => {
   if (msg.type() === 'error'){
       console.log(`Error text: ${msg.text()}`)   
   }  
    
   if(msg.text() === `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()`){
       test.fail()
   }        
})

What should I add more to this code.
I want the test to fail as soon as it sees a 500 error message.

Using an expect would fail the test: expect(msg.text() === "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()").tobe(false)

A [mcve] would be good, so we can see how this call is being used. At least share the full test case, but preferably a test page and full, runnable harness code.

Here is a new version of that listener that would do the job.
I not sure your way is the best practice for your test-case, but in any case here's the code:
page.on("console", (msg) => {
    if (msg.type() !== "error") return; // Inverted if statement

    console.log(`Error text: ${msg.text()}`);

    // Check that error txt is not the specific txt, otherwise- fail test
    expect(msg.text().trim()).not.toEqual(
      "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 ()"
    );
  });

Please note the use of trim method is very important, since in most cases msg.text contains a space at the end of the string.
